# Angular Post Binary Data

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to post binary data using the code below :

```
let headers = new Headers()
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')

this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/api/load",
    requestBytes,
    {
      headers: headers
    }).subscribe((data) => {
        console.log("success!!!")
    })
```

`requestBytes` is of the type `Uint8Array`

The request payload looks like this

```
{
   "0": 10,
   "1": 1,
   "2": 49
}
```

As you can see this appears to be a dict while I was anticipating it to be a byte array. This causes confusion on the server.

I tried changing the `Content-Type` to `application/octet-stream` and passing in the `buffer` instead of array but that didn't help too. The payload in that case is coming out to be empty.

Comment: Use `application/octet-stream` and send `requestBytes.buffer` instead of `requestBytes`.

Comment: @AnshumanJaiswal tried that as mentioned in the last block of my question

Answer (score 0):

Had to manually create the request using `XMLHttpRequest`.

The final code looks something like this :

```
const httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
httpRequest.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/api/restaurant/load', true)
httpRequest.responseType = "arraybuffer"
httpRequest.send(requestBytes)
```